# Proving that two sets of strings are equal

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Let $A=(\Sigma, Q, q_1, F, \delta)$ be a finite **deterministic** automaton (I.e. $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to Q$) such that $Q=\{q_1,...,q_m\}$.

Let's define foreach $i,j\in\{1,...,m\}$, $k\in\{0,1,...,m\}$

(Note: the $\delta$ below is the extension of $\delta$ to $\Sigma^*$)

$L_{i,j}^k=\{w\in\Sigma^*|\delta(q_i,w)=q_j \land \forall u\in PREFIX(w)-\{\epsilon,w\}, \delta(q_i,u)=q_x\to x\leq k\}$

Now let's define the following sets recursively:

For all $i,j\in\{1,...,m\}$:
$M_{i,j}^0=\{\sigma\in\Sigma|\delta(q_i,\sigma)=q_j\}\cup\begin{cases}
\emptyset, \text{if $i\neq j$} \\
\{\epsilon\}, \text{if $i=j$}
\end{cases}$

For all $i,j,k\in\{1,...,m\}$: 
$M_{i,j}^k=M_{i,k}^{k-1}\cdot (M_{k,k}^{k-1})^* \cdot M_{k,j}^{k-1}\cup M_{i,j}^{k-1}$

Prove that for all $i,j\in\{1,...,m\}$ and $k\in\{0,1,...,m\}$ we get $L_{i,j}^k=M_{i,j}^k$.

---

I've tried to prove it by induction on $k$ but failed.

(Note: I've encountered these sets in the proof of the Theorem that says that every regular language has a regular expression)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the *meaning* of these sets?

Comment: @Raphael I've encountered these sets in the proof of the theorem that says: every regular language has a corresponding regular expression.  My university book claims that the sets are the same and doesn't bother to prove why they are the same.

Comment: In the definition of $L^k_{i,j}$ the typing for $\delta$ seems incorrect.  Since the question is sort of a flurry of notation, you probably want $\delta : Q\times \Sigma^* \to Q$.

Comment: @Louis The $\delta$ in $L_{i,j}^k$ is the extension of $\delta$ to $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: @MathNerd: I'm aware, but really the obligation is on you, since you didn't bother to write things out.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not totally clear what are your main obstacles to get the proof done.

Note that $L_{i,j}^k$ is the set of all strings $w$ on a path $\pi$ from $q_i$ to $q_j$ such that for each intermediate state $q_x$ we have $x\le k$; i.e., all intermediate states have index at most $k$.

Consider state $q_k$.
Now either the path $\pi$ does not enter $q_k$ at all: then all indices are at most $k-1$ meaning that $w$ belongs to $L_{i,j}^{k-1}$. Or it may enter $q_k$ one or more times. Thus the path is of the form $\pi: q_i \leadsto q_k \leadsto \dots \leadsto q_k \leadsto q_j$, where the subpaths may start and end in $q_k$, but do not pass that state. So the string $w$ can be partitioned into strings that belong to $L_{i,k}^{k-1}$, $L_{k,k}^{k-1}$, ..., $L_{k,k}^{k-1}$, $L_{k,j}^{k-1}$.

That should prove that $L_{i,j}^{k} = L_{i,k}^{k-1} ( L_{k,k}^{k-1} )^*L_{k,j}^{k-1} \cup L_{i,j}^{k-1}$ (or at least the inclusion from left to right, the other inclusion follows similar argumentation).

With this knowledge the induction is on the subscript $k$, and the induction step is

- If $L_{i,j}^{k-1} = M_{i,j}^{k-1}$ for *all* $i,j$ then $L_{i,j}^{k} = M_{i,j}^{k}$ for *all* $i,j$.

This should be obvious, just plug in the equations we have.

Comment: Thanks, **Intuitively** I understand that it says what you wrote but I cannot **prove** it rigorously. How can I show  that $L_{i,j}^k=M_{i,j}^k$ by showing $L_{i,j}^k\subseteq M_{i,j}^k$ and $M_{i,j}^k\subseteq L_{i,j}^k$. I've tried induction but I failed to show it.

Comment: I see. Only inclusions for the $L_{ij}^k = \dots L_{ij}^{k-1} \dots$ side need to be proved. Stepping between $M_{ij}^k$ and $L_{ij}^k$ is then easy.